# Maximum Response time meaning?

Tags: sensor, frequency-response

I have a sensor, [the manual](http://sensing.honeywell.com/index.php?ci_id=49841) of the which says it has a maximum response time of 1 msec. Does it mean the sensor takes at least 1 msec to respond or at max 1 msec to respond? I am confused because providing least response time makes sense, and here it is given as max. So what does maximum response time denote? How should I interpret it?

Answer (score 1):

It will never take any longer than 1 ms to respond.

Comment: Thanks for immediate reply. 
Does it mean it has a flat response to frequencies above 1 kHz? / So the sensor can capture signals with frequencies greater than 1 kHz?

Comment: There may be a devil hiding in the details, like overshoot so it responds in sub-ms but takes longer to settle but otherwise I would say a fairly flat response to 1 kHz is a reasonable assumption. Measure it and post the results!

Comment: I would like to know about frequency response for frequencies above 1 kHz (say 3 kHz). Can anything be said about this from response time?

Comment: That's pushing the envelope but a -6dB/decade at some frequently is a resonable assumption. If you really need the bandwidth, find the crossover frequency and have an +6 dB/octave slope from that point to cancel it out up to some resonable level. That's how you make cheap speakers sound like expensive ones. And I can already hear the angry audiophiles coming.

Comment: No, it would mean a (fairly) flat response for frequencies below 500Hz. You can make no assumptions whatever for its behaviour even at 1 kHz let alone higher frequencies.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Sure I can :-) They might not hold in the end but it's worth a shot to buy it and test it.

Comment: May well be worth testing. But a better assumption would be a 2nd order rolloff (12dB/octave) above some resonant frequency, probably not much above 500Hz.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Let's see what OP can come up with for test bench to stimulate it at high frequency. The resonance frequently would be the Helmholtz resonator from the cavity itself, plus probably the suspension if the membrane.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that it will take up to 1 ms to reach a certain percentage of the correct value. e.g., If the input pressure goes from 0 to max it may take up to 1 ms to reach 90% of final value. In this sense it will resemble an R-C filter.

> I would like to know about frequency response for frequencies above 1 kHz (say 3 kHz). Can anything be said about this from response time?

It's probably not going to be good. The output signal will look like a low-pass filtered version of the input signal and any transient or sharp edges will be missing.